# How do I enter the @ sign in the Windows 7 logon screen?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, login

Assuming you have a password that includes the @ sign – how do you enter that in the Windows 7 logon screen?

The workaround I have found so far is to use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (on the number pad). This works, but is cumbersome.

I am guessing that this is a non-issue on a US keyboard? Does it work?

On the keyboard I am using (Swiss German) you need to press <kbd>ALTGR</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get the @ symbol and the logon screen does not recognize this combination – it doesn't add a character bullet to the text box.

---

*Update:* This morning I tried to login and everything just worked. Bummer. That was the lock screen, though. So next, I logged out and there: I can't do any <kbd>ALTGR</kbd> combinations (so that rules out the German-German hypothesis) – but <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> *does* work. Hm…

Comment: Check the upper-left corner of the login screen for the language/keyboard menu and make sure that it's set correctly for your keyboard.

Comment: Does shift+2 work?

Comment: Have you tried "Ease of Access" - On Screen Keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that you already have your Swiss layout at logon. If it seems to be German (Z vs. Y), maybe try <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> for the @ (German-German).

This is the registry key where Windows 7 sets the layouts used at logon:

```
HKEY_Users\.Default\Keyboard Layout\Preload
```

German has the code 407. Swiss (German) should be 807 [according to this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) (Thanks [MSalters](https://superuser.com/users/73829/msalters) and [Daren Thomas](https://superuser.com/users/32836/daren-thomas) for the enlightenment and yes your link is the better one).

[How to...](http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-do-i-configure-default-keyboard-layout-during-login)

Comment: wow. i have a `HKEY_Users\.Default\Keyboard Layout\Preload\1`set to 409, which is Ukranian. scary... switched it to `0001041F` and now I'm locked out :(

Comment: ok. so this works, except that the list shown on the page linked to by @TheUser1024 might be buggy... this one worked better: http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-do-i-configure-default-keyboard-layout-during-login (and it also states that 409 is English (United States), which makes a lot more sense...)

Comment: There might be some confusion between hexadecimal and decimal numbers. [This Microsoft table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx) is more detailed and lists both.

Answer (score 3):

Set your system profile's regional settings to match yours:

[image]